# The dynamic registeration of char devices assigns major number for my char device that doesn't correspond to Documentation/devices.txt. Why is that?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Concretely, I use the following function to register my character device:

```
int alloc_chrdev_region(dev_t *first, unsigned int firstminor, unsigned int cnt, char *name);
```

Good enough. Now I print the major number assigned and it gives me: 251.

Now move to [Chapter 3 of Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch03.pdf), Page 5. This paragraph:

*Some major device numbers are statically assigned to the most common devices. A
list of those devices can be found in Documentation/devices.txt within the kernel
source tree. The chances of a static number having already been assigned for the use
of your new driver are small, however, and new numbers are not being assigned. So,
as a driver writer, you have a choice: you can simply pick a number that appears to
be unused, or you can allocate major numbers in a dynamic manner. Picking a num-
ber may work as long as the only user of your driver is you; once your driver is more
widely deployed, a randomly picked major number will lead to conflicts and trouble.*

I thus go to `Documentatio/devices.txt` and search for `251`, the character device major number. But it isn't there. Why is that? Am I missing something?

Comment: Because you let it assign the number dynamically. That file only contains the statically assigned numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Barmar in the comments: the major numbers for specific devices listed in [devices.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devices.txt) are for statically assigned device numbers. This means that if you are writing a driver for a device that fits into one of the categories defined in devices.txt, you could hard-code that major device number into your driver, but you would likely run into conflicts with other drivers.

You are using the correct method of dynamically allocating your device number, as it lets the kernel choose where to put your device driver. Since you let the kernel assign your major number, it's going to choose whatever it wants and is free.

By the way, I don't know what version of devices.txt you're looking at, but if you look at the [latest one hosted on lxr.free-electrons.com (same as above link)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devices.txt), you can see that major numbers 240-254 are reserved for local and experimental use. In my experience, if you're working on your own simple driver, you will get major numbers in this range most of the time.

### TL;DR

The major number 251 *is* listed in the current version of [devices.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devices.txt). It falls in the local/experiment range of major numbers, which is where the kernel will usually start grabbing major numbers from when allowed to do so dynamically, unless told otherwise.